# Use values in the url

Tags: java, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I wanna store the values available in the url give: https://www.example.org/womens-clothing/c-msh10 and use only women and clothing from the url mentioned.

Can anyone help me with the logic.

Thanks in advance.
Raj

Comment: You mean extracting strings from the url itself not from the response it generates? It's a simple string operation (hint: regex), so what did _you_ try already?

Comment: Hi,

https://www.example.com/womens-clothing/c-msh10  https://www.example.com/womens-clothing-ethnic-wear/c-msh1012  

Depending on the value of text mentioned after c-mshxx. I need to fetch the value from the page url, store them in a string and then use only those text left after .com/ and before /c-msh10xx.

Can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Raj

Comment: SO is _not_ a gimme-teh-codez site, so please try something yourself first and _then_ we can help you with the problems you're facing. It's also very unclear of what "Depending on the value of text mentioned after c-mshxx" means so you'd need to specify anyways (in your question, not a comment).

Comment: In a controller you can set a path/request mapping after the root "/" as variables and check them as parameters. Look at point 22.3.2 from SPRING MVC: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on how you are constructing your URL, but those parts of it should be variables right within your request.

For example:

```
${host}/${parentCategory}/${baseProduct}
```

Where

${host} = https://www.example.org

${parentCategory} = womens-clothing

${baseProduct} = c-msh10

Try debugging your request to see what exactly the names of the variables are that you need, or just use a simple regex to take the URL and extract from there. You have plenty of options.